# Return values in Datatables editable table are the most recent edit for all edited items

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using Datatables jeditable, and I'm able to POST updated data to the database, but after the first edit, the echo back to the table is showing the most recent edit.  For example, I make an edit, and it displays the new value + "server updated" in the field.  I make an edit to another field in that same column (different row), and the table displays the new value + "server updated", but then the initial row also shows that most recent value.  The database is correct, so this is an issue with the way the value is being handled on the return.

here's the code.  any ideas on why the most recent update is showing for all updated fields?

```
                    var oTable = [];
                $('.myTable').each(function() {
                  //  var tid = $(this).attr('id');
                    //alert(tid);
                    var obj = {};
                    obj=$('#'+$(this).attr('id')).dataTable({
                        bFilter: false,                        
                        sPaginationType: 'full_numbers',
                        bSort: true
                        aoColumns: [
                            {bSortable: false},
                            {bSortable: false},
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            {
                                data: " {'E':'Letter E','F':'Letter F','G':'Letter G', 'selected':'F'}",
                                type: 'select',
                                submit: 'ok'
                            },
                            null
                        ]
                    });
                    oTable.push(obj);
                }); 

                $('[id^="rnote"]').on('click',
                        function() {
                            var tid = $(this).attr('id');
                            var tabnum = tid.slice(5,6);
                            var ind = tabnum-1;
                            var aPos = oTable[ind].fnGetPosition(this);
                            var selrow = oTable[ind].fnGetData(aPos[0]);
                            var stnum = selrow[0];  //store
                            var supnum = selrow[2]; //supplier number
                            var invnum = selrow[4]; //invoice number
                            var row = aPos[0];
                            $('.editable',oTable[ind].fnGetNodes()).editable('edit_errorcode.php', {
                                callback: function(sValue, y) {
                                    oTable[ind].fnUpdate(sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1]);
                                },
                                submitdata: function(value, settings) {
                                    return {
                                        column: oTable[ind].fnGetPosition(this)[2],
                                        stnum: stnum,
                                        supnum: supnum,
                                        invnum: invnum
                                    };
                                },
                                submit: 'Save',
                                placeholder: ''
                            });
                        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this.  The problem was the aPos (position) values on the callback.  They weren't being updated with the newly updated row.  I reset the aPos variable in the callback to make sure it's using the correct position, and this fixed the problem:

```
                                $('.editable',oTable[ind].fnGetNodes()).editable('edit_errorcode.php', {
                                callback: function(sValue, y) {
                                    aPos = oTable[ind].fnGetPosition(this);  //added this line
                                    oTable[ind].fnUpdate(sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1]);
                                },
```